# function to change language object

Tags: 6, i18n-l10n

I know this question may get the dafs-adrenalin of some of you viewers going. But I'm just recently getting my head in there with php and drupal and have been searching the api and googled a possible function only to find functions that did all sorts of other stuff.

It's that I have this custom logic where I want to change the language object after I've set a `$_COOKIE['lang']`. The value of the cookie lang would be a language code like `en` or `fr`. And going `$language->language -> $_COOKIE['lang'];` is pretty rediculous.

So the question maybe then is: I Know the value of `$language->language`, now I want to use the function that Drupal uses in core to construct the entire language object. This way the language object actually changes after the cookies is set and the locale module can to it's work to load the site in the new language?

Comment: Sorry what's the question? Are you looking for a Drupal API function that will assign the language set by you in the `$_COOKIE` back to the global `$language` object automatically?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I was thinking i18n API but like you say  it must be the Drupal API that will provide me this function to assign the language set by the `$_COOKIE` back to the global `$language` automatically, yes indeed.

Comment: I very much doubt there will be...why not just write one? `function reassign_language() { global $language; $language->language = $_COOKIE['lang']; }` There's no reason that Drupal would include a function to handle/reverse the logic in custom code that you've written

Comment: Yes but that would keep the global $language in it's original language and just change the value of that `$language->language` attribute to the new one provided by that cookie. So after I would have done this assignment like I posed in my question and would set in your function, I would go `global $language; var_dump($language);` In my browserwindow, this var_dump would then return something like `object(stdClass)#3 (11) { ["language"]=> string(2) "fr" ["name"]=> string(5) "Dutch"`...and so on, with all the values of the rest of the keys in the array still set to dutch.

Comment: OK I get you, I'll add an answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The list of language objects is built up by the core function [`language_list()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/language_list/6), which you can use to overwrite the global `$language` object if you need to:

```
// Get the list of languages
$languages = language_list();

// Set up the new language code
$new_lang_code = 'fr';

// Make sure the required language object is actually set
if (isset($languages[$new_lang_code])) {
  // Overwrite the global language object
  global $language;
  $language = $languages[$new_lang_code];
}
```