# How to change Drupal's default language programmatically?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I am trying to change the Drupal's default language programmatically  but haven't found the codes/function. Any suggestions?

Comment: At a guess... `$langs = language_list('enabled'); variable_set('language_default', $langs[$some_langcode]);`

Comment: @Clive, close, but not quite.  See my answer for the correct code.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a corrected and tested version of the code posted by @Clive in a comment to the OP:

```
$langs = language_list(); // Note: No argument
// debug($langs, '$langs');
$langcode = 'en';
variable_set('language_default', $langs[$langcode]);
```

The code snippet above assumes that the two-character code that you assign to `$langcode` is enabled.  Uncomment the call to `debug` to see the languages that are enabled on your site and what array indices they use.

Note that the setting will not take effect until the next page load.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the code and its pretty simple .

```
//Set Default language
    $default_language = array('language' => 'en-US', 
                            'name' => 'English', 
                            'native' => 'English', 
                            'direction' => LANGUAGE_LTR, 
                            'enabled' => (int) TRUE, 
                            'plurals' => 0, 
                            'formula' =>'',
                            'domain' => '', 
                            'weight' => 0, 
                            'javascript' => '');
variable_set('language_default', (object) $default_language) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

By implementing the following hook: hook_language_negotiation_info()
and here is a full example

http://tassaf.moriamedia.com/drupal-7-default-language-after-translation/

Answer (score 0):

Just setting the variable is not always enough. By the time you've done so, the Drupal language negotiation function may have already run, and it will not react to this variable change. The proper way to do this is as follows:

```
// Get the list of languages
$languages = language_list();

// Set up the new language code
$new_lang_code = 'fr';

// Make sure the required language object is actually set
if (isset($languages[$new_lang_code])) {
  // Overwrite the global language object
  global $language;
  $language = $languages[$new_lang_code];
}
```

This has been documented in other questions such as:
[function to change language object](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23679/function-to-change-language-object)

An additional option is to write your own custom language negotiation hook:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!language.api.php/function/hook_language_negotiation_info/7